# How to change appearance of text in Word without changing actual formattting?

Tags: ms-word, formatting, accessibility

bit of a vague question perhaps but I'm trying to create an accessibility feature that essentially changes the appearance of text in Word, so the first three letters of each word are in bold for accessibility.

I've thus far only worked in VBA, but the problem is that I don't want to change the actual formatting of the text within Word, but just the appearance. When I download a document, I want to be able to run this code to change the view, edit the document with tracked changes, and then change the view back once I'm done.

I could feasibly use vba to bold the first three letters of each word in tracked changes and then at the end of the document have another macro that removes all track changes introducing bold formatting, but this would make the process of editing in tracked changes exceptionally difficult. And I wouldn't just be able to hide format changes, as the editing I am doing requires making other different formatting changes.

So my question is, should I approach this with a new programming language, and if so, could you point me in the right direction of going about this?

Thanks in advance, and apologies if this isn't the right forum to post this sort of general question - I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to make text appear bold without actually making it bold in Word. If there was such a hack, it might *cause* an accessibility problem. I can turn on "format changes" in my screen reader settings to be notified when I'm navigating through text that has a different format. If you are trying to visually style the first three letters of a word and that styling has meaning, then that meaning also has to be conveyed to screen readers too.

You mentioned you're trying to create an accessibility feature by doing this but as mentioned above, this might cause an accessibility problem. Perhaps some more detail on what you're trying to do will help.